# How to find pumpkins in the Minecraft inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Where can I find pumpkins in the Minecraft creative inventory? I am  trying to make a snow man and I can't seem to find any pumpkins!

Comment: Are you sure you used the right tag for this question?

Comment: Are you trying to ask where pumpkins are in the creative mode menu or where to find pumpkins in survival mode?

Comment: If you can't find one, use the search function(compass icon on creative menu), or just run this command : `/give @p pumpkin`

Answer (score 3):

The pumpkin block is located in the "Building Blocks" menu of the creative inventory, about halfway down.

[image: Pumpkin Block]

Comment: Also if you click on the compass icon (top right) you can search for any item by name.